# 1 session (id) on the same domain in php

Tags: php, ajax, session

I'm running PHP7 on a debian 8 server. I host 2 domains on this server. What I want is 1 session_id per domain. I'm having trouble changing session information in an ajax/php call in the php file because the session_id is different.

there's a **setup.php** which is included in **index.php** and **calledByAjax.php** at the top of both files. In **setup.php** I run `SESSION_START()`.

*Below explains the problem in code.*

domain.com/helpers/**Setup.php**

```
session_start();
```

domain.com/**index.php**

```
include("helpers/settings.php" );
echo session_id(); // output: c4eapvno37vg027aba4pk2gl06

<script>
ajax.open("POST", "http://www.domain.com/calls/calledByAjax.php.php", true);
// response output: asdf98asdfahasdfl
</script>
```

domain.com/**calledByAjax.php**

```
echo session_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are unique to a domain name because cookies are. You can, however, share a session cookie over multiple subdomains, provided that the main domain enforces a www subdomain and if you prefix the cookie name with a dot:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

> `$domain`
>
> Cookie domain, for example 'www.php.net'. To make cookies visible on all subdomains then the domain must be prefixed with a dot like '.php.net'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the ajax call. I called to http://**www**.domain.com/--- from http://domain.com/----

```
ajax.open("POST", "http://domain.com/calls/calledByAjax.php.php", true);
```